# How to calculate a molecule's oscillator strength?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

I was wondering how to calculate a molecule's (e.g. biphenyl) oscillator strength using a very simplified model.

If I want to calculate a molecule's excited states a good start is something like a particle in a box model, which won't come up with even nearly exact energies but with an idea of energy values. Is there anything similiar for the oscillator strength which would deliver simplified solutions?

Comment: The simplest would be to use Huckel theory in one of its variants. Using symmetry  one can then determine which transitions are allowed or forbidden.  Knowing electron density approximations to transition moments can be calculated. Btw, biphenyl may not be a good starting point as its geometry is variable depending the the angle between rings.